# DisplayCAL profile loader: display profile couldn't be loaded; what does it mean?

Tags: display, dell, laptop

I installed Linux Ubuntu 18.04 on one of my old laptop (Latitude E6430).

It works beautifully and is even much faster than Win7 which was on there before.

However, when I log in X-Windows, I get a message saying that a display profile could not be loaded:

> DisplayCAL Profile Loader 3.5
>
> P7FFH-140WD1 @ 0, 0, 1600x900: Display profile couldn't be loaded.

The message can be discarded and I can even mark it as "do not show again". So I suppose it's just a warning. That being said, I'm wondering what that message means since the display looks as expected (correct sizes, perfect colors, nothing to complain about).